# Specific cross-join query

Tags: sql, oracle

Got table A, B and C. All tables have primary keys. Tables B and C both have field id_a which is a link to key of table A.
I want to write a select statement which would select all rows from table A, one column from table C and one from B. But they must be joined like 2 independant columns. So that for one key from table A, there must be max(B,C) rows which contain all data from A plus those 2 colums, for expample:

```
------------------
a11....a1n|b11|c11
a11....a1n|b12|c12
a11....a1n|b13|null
a11....a1n|b14|null
a21....a2n|b21|c21
a21....a2n|b22|c22
a21....a2n|null|c23
a21....a2n|null|c24
a21....a2n|null|c25
```

{bXY} means that it is a value from B, linked to value X from a, and Y is just enumeration

Of course, for all values from tables B and C must correspond to table A by their id_a field.

Table structures:

```
Table A:
id int autoincrement
name varchar 

Table B:
id int autoincrement
id_a int 
value_b float

Table C:
id int autoincrement
id_a int
value_c int
```

Comment: I have one doubt on your expectation .. 

please tell me if table B has 4 record and table C has 2 record .. 
so for every row in table A you want 4 rows .. 

say Table A has 5 record then you want 20 records in your output ..??

Comment: No, not like this. I want for every row from A max(B,C) rows WHICH CORRESPOND to that row from A. So if for row 1 from A I have 4 rows in B and 2 rows in C, i want 4 rows. If for row 2 from A I have 2 rows in B and 5 in C, I want 5 rows. So 4+5=9 rows all in all

Comment: then please edit your question and put sample data and expected result for second scenario ..

Comment: if possible to paste can you give table structures also .

Comment: What you have shown is not possible without a way to group the data from tables b & c. Otherwise 4 rows of b and 5 of c will give you 20 rows, not 9.

Comment: Thats why i'm posting it here. B and C are not connected in any way, except they both link to A

Comment: Without a relation between them you will end up joining every applicable row from B with every applicable row from C. ie b11 in `a11....a1n|b11|c11` would also show up as `a11....a1n|b11|c12`. You could possibly create some sort of stored proc that would get the a=b values in one query then the a=c values in another and then creates the rows like you describe, but you won't get it through regular join syntax and a single query.

Comment: What you are  asking for is not a CROSS JOIN.  CROSS JOINs are cartesian products, they produce a row for every possible permutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible if you generate empty rows for table containing less rows. Each row from B and C is assigned a number. Full outer join adds missing rows.

```
select a.*, value_b, value_c
from TableA a
left join
(
   select nvl(b.id_a, c.id_a) AS id_a, b.value_b, c.value_c
     from 
     (
        select b.id_a, b.value_b,
               row_number() over (partition by b.id_a order by b.id) rn
          from TableB b
     ) b
     full outer join
     (
        select c.id_a, c.value_c,
               row_number() over (partition by c.id_a order by c.id) rn
          from TableC c
     ) c
       on b.id_a = c.id_a
      and b.rn = c.rn
) maxRows
  on a.id = maxRows.id_a
```

You can check it at [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2149/1)

Comment: Pff, after thorough testing, i fugured out that this syntax does not work in oracle 9(((

Comment: @YoZH what part is not supported?

Comment: It gives extra records. To get rid of them, I replaced FULL OUTER JOIN with WHERE b.id_a (+) = c.id_a  and b.rn(+) = c.rn

Comment: @YoZH If I read this correctly you replaced full join with right join. This cannot be right. Could you post your current query and results in your question? Or setup a Fiddle?

Comment: I dont know how to setup a fiddle for Oracle 9i, but i entered your example in sqldeveloper. it returned me this:
http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6105/52248703.0/0_1abc1e_1441cff1_M.jpg

Comment: If you run part after left join only, what do you get? (part inside parenthesis, without TableA)

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following for a start: (based on SQLServer rather than Oracle)

```
declare @AValues varchar(max)
select @AValues = ISNULL(@AValues,'')+ a.A_column + ',' from tableA a

select A_PrimaryKey, @AValues, b.B_column, c.C_column from
(
  select b.id_a A_PrimaryKey from tableB b
  union
  select c.id_a A_PrimaryKey from tableC c
) x
left join tableB b on b.id_a = x.A_PrimaryKey
left join tableC c on c.id_a = x.A_PrimaryKey
```

To further improve, you can replace the variable @AValues by a  SQL sub-query that will return all the rows from TableA as a comma seperated list.

The union between TableB and TableC will give you all the primary key values of TableA that you are interested in, effectively max of rows in TableB and TableC. The left join will give you the values from either TableB or TableC.

Hope this helps to some extent!

Comment: if the union returns 10 rows for id_a = 1, won't your first join return 100 rows for every b.id_a = 1 (because every A_PrimaryKey in the union = 1)? and the second join 10 000 rows?

Comment: 'union' returns only distinct values, only 'union all' will return all the values